# What's UI that mail.app in iphone use for editing messag body

Tags: iphone, sendmessage

I'm a new iphone programmer. I want to know what UI that can handle HTML and editable same as reply or forward message in mail.app .. is it UIWebView or UITextView that applied with UIScrollView?
I want this UI to reply and forward message and can be saved message to database. So, I cannot use mailcomposer controller because I cannot get data that user input in to, cc, bcc, subject and message body field.

Can any one help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Three20 library](http://three20.info). It has a replication of the mail compose UI that you can use however you'd like.